# Conceptual quest: Chain of communication along classes

Tags: java, object, communication

This is more of a conceptual design question, so I hope this is the right place to ask this.

I need to connect a chain of objects together by having the output of one class feed into the input for another. I initially handled this by having having a data structure feed itself into the next output by using a loop for iterate over the list of objects, but I realised this only works if the communication is singular (ie. a -> b -> c -> d, etc only one output can be feed into the next input)

What I need to do be able to accomodate communication where
a -> b -> c -> d where say any class and send more than one output (not at the same time) to the next class. eg. b might send something, then pause, then send something else based on an input from A. This is all running on the same thread.

My question is what approaches can I take (language is Java to achieve this). I've currently looked into: - Opening some sort of stream between objects, a chain of observers and subjects (bad practice from what I read online to do this) and various design patterns, but they don't really seem sensible for the task at hand.  Any suggestions would be fantastic.

Comment: Sounds like a good scenario for using JMS

Comment: Thanks for that - I will look into it right away!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself yet, but this sounds to me like a great job for [rxJava](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/).